# Supervisord (exit status 1; not expected) centos python

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, centos6, supervisord

Ran into additional issue with Supervisord.

Centos 6.5
supervisor
python 2.6 installed with the OS
python 2.7 installed in /usr/local/bin

supervisord program settings

```
[program:inf_svr]
process_name=inf_svr%(process_num)s
directory=/opt/inf_api/
environment=USER=root,PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/
command=python2.7 /opt/inf_api/inf_server.py --port=%(process_num)s
startsecs=2
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=4
numprocs_start=8080
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stdout.log
```

I can run inf_server.py with:

```
python2.7 inf_server.py --port=8080
```

with no problems.
I made sure the files were executable (that was my problem before).

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
I cant get it to even launch a basic python script without failing.
Started by commenting out the old program, adding a new one and then putting in:

```
command=python /opt/inf_api/test.py
```

where test.py just writes something to the screen and to a file.  Fails with exit status 0.
So I started adding back in the location of python (after discovering it with 'which python')

```
environment=PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin
```

Tried putting the path in single quote, tried adding USER=root, to the environment, tried adding

```
directory=opt/inf_api/
```

tried adding

```
user=root
```

All the same thing, exit status 0.   Nothing seems to added to any log files either, except what Im seeing from the debug of supervisord.

Man I am at a loss.

Comment: Try view error log file at /var/log/supervisord/tornado-stderr.log. I found exactly error in this

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an issue with how Supervisord is catching error messages from python. As in it isnt. Im running it to launch a tornado app, that calls a second python file so it can spawn n instances of tornado servers. If there are errors in that second python app, then it isnt catching them and saving them to the log files. I tried all manner of methods but ended up having to catch them myself with try: except: and saving it to my own log files. Probably good paractice anyway but talk about a round about way of going about it.